# exporting a word Document to PDF and saving it on global drive

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

i am facing a little issue. I wrote a small programm with VBA that writes some Data into a word Document and then exports this word Document to PDF. Since this is part of my job I have to save this on a global Drive of my company.

The problem is that somehow exporting takes just very long. For my VBA Code i am using the follwing statement to save it

```
WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat path, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
```

Generally, if I want to export a Word Document and save it **manually** the first time in a certain folder, exporting that file takes also very long. But if I then export another document in this same folder, exporting becomes very fast. So generally how does exporting on a global drive actually work (internally) ?

But somehow my programm is always very slow. I just do not understand why exporting a file by my Programm always takes so long (I am 100 percent sure that is it the exporting that takes so long, and it is just that statement mentioned above that takes so long (`WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat path, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF`) )

Do you guys have any Idea how to make exporting and saving a file quicker.
I would really need help :)

Thank you so much in advance

jonas

Comment: When your macro has to deal with operating system functions, it can slow down a lot. It sounds like once your initial drive connection is made, Windows doesn't have the same overhead to reconnect, so your macro runs more quickly. It's not your code, and there's nothing you can do to speed it up. I've written VBA macros that choose from multiple printers, and the problem is very similar, the macro runs very slowly.

Comment: One thing you might try if your company network configuration will allow, is to have a local folder on your hard drive that syncs with the global folder. Writing to your disk will be quick, then the sync operation can take its time.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with any other folder on the disk?

Comment: Have you also tried using the [ExportAsFixedFormat2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat2) method instead? Or just try to play with different parameters?

Comment: thank you so much for your answers, I really appreciate that. The problem is that the excel that has/executes this VBA code actually has to be on the global drive and cannot be put on one local spot since more users should be able to use that ( not simultaneously ). But regarding @John and @K idea: I could have every user of that program (since they are known) have a local folder where the documents are stored. Then I would just have to synchronized those separate (multiple) folders with the one big global folder. Would that be a good idea? How would you implement it. Or any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Eugene I will try and give feedback (regarding ExportAsfixedFormat2) and yes I face the same problem with any folder